# Jquery modal close in an UpdatePanel when another field updates

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel

I have an UpdatePanel with an ASP button inside of it which initiates a search (in code behind) on the click event. A drop down list then updates with in the same UpdatePanel with information from the search.

I have configured a JQuery modal dialog box to pop up during the search time, but I'd like to have it vanish when the dropdown menu is updated after the search. I'm not sure what (event, ui) I should use for the close, or if this is the correct way to close it at all.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#dialog1").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, resizable: false, close: function (event, ui) { } });

    $("#<%=btnItemNumSearch.ClientID%>").click(function () {

        $("#dialog1").dialog("open");


});
});
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function () {
$("#dialog1").dialog({ autoOpen: false, modal: true, resizable: false, close: function (event, ui) { } });

$("#<%=btnItemNumSearch.ClientID%>").click(function () {

        $("#dialog1").dialog("open");

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the jQuery BlockUI Plugin to get the job done, and used the jQuery ajaxComplete() to close the window. This worked properly in an ASP.NET UpdatePanel with the following code.  http://jquery.malsup.com

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    // bind your jQuery events here initially

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnMyButton.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#dialog1') });
        });
        $.ajax({
            complete: function () {
                // unblock when remote call returns 
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });

    });
});

var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

prm.add_endRequest(function () {

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=btnMyButton.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#dialog1') });

        });

        $.ajax({
            complete: function () {
                // unblock when remote call returns 
                $.unblockUI();
            }
        });
    });

});
</script>

<div id="dialog1" title="Item Search" style="display: none">
Searching the database, please wait...

</div>
```